# Resolution required when creating a new bug

Tags: jira

Whenever I edit a bug in jira where the resolution is set to unresolved I get an error indicating the resolution is a required field.  Sometimes the bug hasn't yet been resolved but will be and I just need to update some info on the ticket. 
Resolution does not appear on that edit screen until I try and save, then it pops up.  I also have a POST function set in the issue workflow transitions that should update the resolution on the bug.  I am new to serving as scrum master so I am sure I am missing something but I haven't been able to figure it out.  Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The resolution field is probably set to "required" in the admin settings for field types. This is tricky to get working as intended, and probably unnecessary for your application, so I suggest simply clearing that setting.